# Proving a property of a prime number (Elementary number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove the following statement.

For all prime numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, $a
^2 + b^2
\neq c^2$
.

What i tried

Proving by contradiction

Assume the negation of the statement

There exists prime numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a
^2 + b^2
= c^2$

Since we know that all prime number except $2$ is also an odd number
 Then we let $a=2n+1$ $b=2l+1$ 
Then we have

$4l^{2}+4l+1+4k^{2}+4k+1=c^{2}$

$4l^{2}+4l+4k^{2}+4k+2=c^{2}$

$2(2l^{2}+2l+2k^{2}+2k+1)=c^{2}$

From this expression,since $c^{2}$ is even then $c$ is even. But we have a case where $c=2$, so if $c=2$, then $c^{2}=4$ and

$2l^{2}+2l+2k^{2}+2k+1=2$. Then

$2l^{2}+2l+2k^{2}+2k=1$ and

$l^{2}+l+k^{2}+k=0.5$

Which is not possible since the sum of integers have to also be an integer

Which contradicts with the face that $c$ is either odd or has a value of $2$ for

it to be a prime number

Is my proof correct.Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Hint: either all of $a,b,c$ are odd, or one (or more) of them is $2$. Derive a contradiction in both cases separately

Comment: Can we just assume that all prime numbers except $2$ is also an odd number? Since there is no definitive for it.

Comment: This isn't something you jus assume, you can actually prove it.

Comment: I finally completed my proof based u gave . Is it correct? Thanks

Comment: You did not check the case when either $a$ or $b$ is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elementary approach: since the only quadratic residues $\pmod{3}$ are $0$ and $1$, if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ at least one number between $a$ and $b$ has to be a multiple of three. With a similar argument $\pmod{4}$ and $\pmod{5}$, we have that $a^2+b^2=c^2$ implies that at least one number between $a$ and $b$ is even, and at least one number among $a,b,c$ is a multiple of five. It follows that no triple of primes is a pythagorean triple.

Comment: Is my proof also correct? Thanks

Comment: @yswong: your proof is correct, but incomplete. You proved that if $a$ and $b$ are both odd, $a^2+b^2$ cannot equal a square. True, but you still needs to prove that $p^2+4$ cannot be the square of a prime.

Comment: (1)Also there is  a need to  consider the case a=b. (2)The case a=2 or b=2 can be done by observing that two squares cannot differ by  exactly 4.

Comment: @user254665: I totally agree.

Comment: By elementary means we can derive the formula for ALL Pythagorean triplets $a,b,c$  with  $a^2+b^2=c^2 $,  as $\{a,b\}=\{m^2-n^2,2 m n\}$ and $c=m^2+n^2$ for some positive integers $m,n$. The only way that $2 m n$ can be prime is for $m=n=1$ which,unfortunately gives $m^2-n^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot find primes $a,b,c$ such that $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ because of an elementary classical result: Take any integers $a,b,c$ such that $(a,b) = 1$; then $a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}$ if and only if $a = u^{2} - v^{2}$, $b = 2uv$, $c = u^{2} + v^{2}$ for some  integers $u, v$ such that $(u,v) = 1$.